# How to set attribute to an XmlNode object which is not set to an instance or object. c#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xmlnode

I cannot figure out how to set a default value to an `XmlNode`.

I have an `XmlNode` called `RequirementMinTime` and I want to set it to the value of "0" when that node is not in the xml document. Here is the code I'm trying which is not working.

```
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlpath, settings);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        doc.Load(reader);

       if (GlobalNode.SelectSingleNode("MinTimeMs") == null)
        {
            RequirementMinTime.Attributes["MinTimeMs"].Value = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            RequirementMinTime = GlobalNode.SelectSingleNode("MinTimeMs");
        }
```

I am getting the following error in the if statement

> "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'"

this is the object declaration:

```
    public static XmlNode RequirementMinTime
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution

```
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlpath, settings);
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    doc.Load(reader);

   if (GlobalNode.SelectSingleNode("MinTimeMs") == null)
    {
        XmlNode newNode = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "MinTimeMs", "");
        newNode.InnerText = "0";
        GlobalNode.AppendChild(newNode);    
        RequirementMinTime = GlobalNode.SelectSingleNode("MinTimeMs");
    }
    else
    {
        RequirementMinTime = GlobalNode.SelectSingleNode("MinTimeMs");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the node, otherwise you can not set a value (assuming your `XmlDocument` is named `xmlDoc`:

```
if (GlobalNode.SelectSingleNode("MinTimeMs") == null)
{
    RequirementMinTime = xmlDoc.CreateElement("MinTimeMs");
    RequiredMinTime.Value = "0";
}
else
{
    RequirementMinTime = GlobalNode.SelectSingleNode("MinTimeMs");
}
```

Comment: im getting the error 
"Cannot implicitly convert 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' to 'System.Xml.XmlNode'"